# Android database on phone

Tags: android, database

I have a problem regarding android database.I have an app which have it's database in assets folder.This app is already installed on the phone and working fine.But now i created another database file(just increase the number of records in the previous database and everything else is same). And put it again in assets folder and replace it with existing database file, and recompile the project. Now in emulator the new database is loading and showing the updated content in database. but when i installed the app again in phone my previous database is showing up and new database is not loading.
But if i uninstall the app from the phone and reinstall it then new database is showing up.

PROBLEM: I just want that if i replace the preexisting app on phone the new database should be loaded, not after uninstalling and then reinstalling the app.
Any suggestion or help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android you must use the [onUpgrade](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) function to update your database from a previous version. This is because Android will only create your database once and from then on out it will just use that one. So you must assign a version code to your new database that is different from the old one and use the onUpgrade to actually perform the change to the new database. All devices that are installing from scratch do not have a current database so they are getting the new one created for them.

Comment: thanks for reply : onUpgrade method will be call when i fist start my activity.How it is related to installing the application? i mean if i m replacing the app then everything should be replaced including database in assets folder

Comment: To replace the app you need to do a full uninstall. When you run adb to install your app it is actually doing a re-install which does not clear out stored application data.

Answer (score 0):

I bet if you clear the data for your app in Settings and relaunch it, it should load the new database. The reason for this has something to do with `SQLiteOpenHelper` copying the database from the assets folder in the APK to the application's data directory on the phone if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise it will load the one on the phone. Unless you specifically access the database from the assets folder each time, it will use the cached version.